# How to open testing menu in android?

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-menu

I am new to android development and i am trying to create a app that will open the hidden testing menu within the app. And I found a code which is given below;

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
in.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TestingSettings");
startActivity(in);
```

I put this code in my **main_activity.java** just under the **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** line, but when i try to open the app in emulator, the app crashes and the logcat logs the error as given below;

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 2517
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TestingSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
at com.freezo.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

and also can someone help me out with how to select phone information and display it within my app

Comment: have you read this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMzZrxjYPaAhVKqY8KHaycBHQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xda-developers.com%2Fcodes-hidden-android%2F&usg=AOvVaw1_zq7oZbz_jibPMTDIdhf2

Comment: @AdernNerk yes i did read that and only after that wanted to make myself an app that can read everything out without me having to enter the codes everytime